# AWS describe snapshots optimization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have been using the aws CLI to get a specific list of snapshots owned by owner-id foo. It has a few useful tags made: created_by, instance_name, etc. I have been trying to tweak out this command to get this information in a readable format:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids foo --filters Name=description,Values="autosnap*" --query 'Snapshots[*].{ID: SnapshotId,StartTime: StartTime,Key:instance_name}'
```

Basically, I'd like it to just return the three columns being queried: ID, StartTime, Key (which contains the instance name). However i get something like:

```
snap-foo    None    2016-12-23T07:00:18.000Z
```

I am reading through AWS documentation and it does mention the --query flag can obtain Tags. My question is: Is there a way to just return the one Tag, labelled instance_name? If so, can you please provide an example? If this is not possible to do with AWS CLI, can you please provide an alternative? Thanks much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tags` is a list. The following works for me:

```
--query 'Snapshots[*].{ID: SnapshotId,StartTime: StartTime,Key:Tags[?Key==`instance_name`].Value[]}'
```